# SQL Server Configuration Manager in docker container

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-for-windows

I am running SQL Server inside a Windows container. Is there a way to run a SQL Server Configuration Manager for a Docker container?

Comment: if you run your docker container in `-net host` mode, you can interact with it just like a remote machine (hence access it over network)

Comment: @Amir Can you provide more information? I'm not sure it has to do with my question.

Comment: Take a look at this: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/scm-services-connect-to-another-computer?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Amir how do I modify my container to use the -net host option? Or do I need to create a new container?

Comment: What is the setup you're using? Are you using linux or windows? please provide some more information (edit and put it in your question)

Comment: @Amir, as I mentioned in the question it a windows container, ie windows for both host and container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190048/discussion-between-amir-and-alexanderm).

Answer (score 0):

If you make your docker container accessible over network, then you can access it exactly like a remote machine, and as it stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/scm-services-connect-to-another-computer?view=sql-server-2017) in Microsoft documentation, you can run SQL Server Configuration Manager for remote machines.

To make your container accessible over network, you should map a port of it to a port on your host, and also run it in `--network host` mode:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:1433 --network host --name my_container my_image
```

explanation:

`-d` : runs the container in detached mode, i.e. in the background

`-p 8000:1433`: Maps port 1433 of container to port 8000 of host (host comes first)

(1433 is the default port for SQL Server)

<s>`--network host`: Doesn't isolate network of container from host, which makes it accessible from outside world</s> (**see update**)

`--name some_name`: names your container for ease of use

`my_image`: the name of the image which the container should be based on that.

After running your container in this way, you can access it on `localhost:8000`

After that, follow the instructions on Microsoft docs ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/scm-services-connect-to-another-computer?view=sql-server-2017))

---

**Update:**
According to [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/), some networking features (namely `--network host`) are not working in windows version, but apparently you don't need it for this case because we just need to access the container from host, not from outside world. Just remove that and try it.

Comment: I'm trying this now and I cant see my docker host to connect. nothing is found with localhost, i need to connect to Microsoft SQL Server Configuration Manager in my docker. thx